# Parenting object moves from the location

Tags: parent

I have made a quarter shape and made the group and parent to 1 empty. In this way i duplicate and flip and rotate and made the rectangular shape. I have 4 empty with there mesh parenting. Now i want to make a single parent of them. I added a new empty selected all the mesh and then the empty and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> object and parent them. But the result is all the alignment i have made goes in one direction. How can i make a new parent from the base mesh as seen below. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the other option? "Keep transforms?"

Comment: @batFINGER a small problem arise now after making the keep transform option it works but i want to bend and use the curve modifier that i cant use for the empty made with keep transform. Any suggestion